# Сохранить WindowState формы в ini файл и получить обратно

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Необходимо сохранить состояние формы (WindowState)+Top,Left,Height,Width при закрытии и восстановить при повторном открытии.
Делаю так:

```
procedure main_form_write(Sen: TForm);
var
  ini_u: TIniFile;
begin
  ini_u := TIniFile.Create(extractfilepath(paramstr(0)) + u_dir);
  try
    if not (Sen.WindowState = wsMaximized) then
    begin
      ini_u.WriteInteger('main', 'Top', Sen.Top);
      ini_u.WriteInteger('main', 'Left', Sen.Left);
      ini_u.WriteInteger('main', 'Height', Sen.Height);
      ini_u.WriteInteger('main', 'Width', Sen.Width);
    end;
    ini_u.WriteInteger('main', 'State', ord(Sen.WindowState));
  finally
    FreeAndNil(ini_u);
  end;
end;

procedure main_form_read(Sen: TForm);
var
  ini_u: TIniFile;
begin
  ini_u := TIniFile.Create(extractfilepath(paramstr(0)) + u_dir);
  try
    Sen.Top := ini_u.ReadInteger('main', 'Top', 100);
    Sen.Left := ini_u.ReadInteger('main', 'Left', 100);
    Sen.Height := ini_u.ReadInteger('main', 'Height', 700);
    Sen.Width := ini_u.ReadInteger('main', 'Width', 1000);
    Sen.WindowState := TWindowState(ini_u.ReadInteger('main', 'State', ord(wsNormal)));
  finally
    FreeAndNil(ini_u);
  end;
end;
```

Если закрыть с состоянием wsMaximized и открыть повторно, то состояние восстановится, но вот если тыкнуть кнопку Restore, то форма изменяется до не известных мне размеров(т.е. я не сохранял и не загружал такие), а именно W320 x H240 x L130 x T130.

Comment: А вы сохраните и загрузите и их тоже

Comment: Попробуйте воспользоваться [GetWindowPlacement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowplacement) и [SetWindowPlacement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowplacement) для получения и установки размеров и положения окна.

Comment: @Kromster если сохранять размеры при развернутом окне приложения, размеры сохраняются максимальные. зачем мне это? при restore окно останется при максимальных размерах. И как вы видите размеры грузятся "main_form_read()"

Comment: Я у себя делал вот так (метод сохранения другой, но смысл, думаю, понятен): `Form.Position := poDesigned; ... восстановление размеров ...; if FWindowData[16] > 0 {флаг развертки} then ShowWindow(Form.Handle, SW_MAXIMIZE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const
  SECTION_NAME = 'WindowPlacement';

procedure TForm1.LoadPlacement(aFileName: string);
var
  Placement: TWindowPlacement;
begin
  with TIniFile.Create(aFileName) do
  try
    FillChar(Placement, SizeOf(Placement), #0);
    Placement.length := SizeOf(Placement);
    if not GetWindowPlacement(Handle, @Placement) then
      raise Exception.Create('GetWindowPlacement faild.');
    with Placement do
    begin
      flags := ReadInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'flags', flags);
      showCmd := ReadInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'showCmd', showCmd);
      with ptMinPosition do
      begin
        X := ReadInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'ptMinPosition.X', X);
        Y := ReadInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'ptMinPosition.Y', Y);
      end;
      with ptMaxPosition do
      begin
        X := ReadInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'ptMaxPosition.X', X);
        Y := ReadInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'ptMaxPosition.Y', Y);
      end;
      with rcNormalPosition do
      begin
        Left := ReadInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'rcNormalPosition.Left', Left);
        Top := ReadInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'rcNormalPosition.Top', Top);
        Right := ReadInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'rcNormalPosition.Right', Right);
        Bottom := ReadInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'rcNormalPosition.Bottom', Bottom);
      end;
    end;
    if not SetWindowPlacement(Handle, @Placement) then
      raise Exception.Create('SetWindowPlacement faild.');
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.SavePlacement(aFileName: string);
var
  Placement: TWindowPlacement;
begin
  with TIniFile.Create(aFileName) do
  try
    FillChar(Placement, SizeOf(Placement), #0);
    Placement.length := SizeOf(Placement);
    if not GetWindowPlacement(Handle, @Placement) then
      raise Exception.Create('GetWindowPlacement faild.');
    with Placement do
    begin
      WriteInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'flags', flags);
      WriteInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'showCmd', showCmd);
      with ptMinPosition do
      begin
        WriteInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'ptMinPosition.X', X);
        WriteInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'ptMinPosition.Y', Y);
      end;
      with ptMaxPosition do
      begin
        WriteInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'ptMaxPosition.X', X);
        WriteInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'ptMaxPosition.Y', Y);
      end;
      with rcNormalPosition do
      begin
        WriteInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'rcNormalPosition.Left', Left);
        WriteInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'rcNormalPosition.Top', Top);
        WriteInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'rcNormalPosition.Right', Right);
        WriteInteger(SECTION_NAME, 'rcNormalPosition.Bottom', Bottom);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score -2):

Сохраняете при закрытии формы? Тогда, сохранять вначале статус формы (Form), проверяете, если статус = 0 (wsNormal), то сохранять и размеры формы

```
    WriteInteger('Main', 'State', Integer(Form.WindowState));
    if integer(Form.WindowState) = 0 then
    begin
      WriteInteger('Main', 'Top', Form.Top);
      WriteInteger('Main', 'Left', Form.Left);
      WriteInteger('Main', 'Width', Form.Width);
      WriteInteger('Main', 'Height', Form.Height);
    end;
```

А читать, как принято...

```
    if ValueExists('Main', 'State') then
      Form.WindowState := TWindowState(ReadInteger('Main', 'State',        
        integer(Main.WindowState)));
    if ValueExists('Main', 'Top') then
      Form.Top := ReadInteger('Main', 'Top', 0);
```

Comment: Вы сами проверяли данный код? Если закрыть приложение при "макс." размере и запустить его снова, оно откроется в "макс." размере, после чего попробуйте его свернуть. оно свернется до размеров которые не задавались и не загружались в/из ini. ну и думаю это те же яйца, только в профиль. И не вижу прикола в ValueExists(), зачем?

Comment: Зачем ерничать? Посмотрите какие параметры положения и размера возвращаются при сворачивании формы в зависимости от установленного при разработке свойства "Position". "Окно свернется....", - естественно! И будут применены или сохраненные в файл, размеры и положение, или в зависимости от выбранного при разработке свойства "Position". Я использую "poDesktopCenter".

Comment: Ваш необоснованный -1 мне "карман" не оторвет, а вот желание показать, как применить TWindowPlacement, извините, пропало.